Powerpc assembly instruction unclear
I am newbie to Assembly coding.
I have the below C code
#define X 8380417
#define INV 0x3802001
int32_t reduce(int64_t a) {

  int32_t t;
  t = (int64_t)(int32_t)a*INV;
  t = (a - (int64_t)t*X) >> 32;
  return t;
}

The assembly generated for the same looks as below for ppc
lis 8,0x380
lis 9,0xff80
ori 8,8,8193
ori 9,9,8191
mullw 8,8,4
mulhw 10,8,9
mullw 11,8,9
addc 4,4,11
adde 3,3,10
blr

I understand [lis 8,0x380 + ori 8,8,8193] = placing QINV in R8
mullw 8,8,4 = multiply last 32 bits of QINV by a -> higher bits of R8 after this still holds 0x380 ?
But how is Q = 8380417 = ff801fff in R9 and then the rest of steps done like adding instead of subtraction?

It's great that you managed to find an answer to your own question!  Post it as an answer instead of editing your post so it's clear that your question has been resolved.

OK , i figured out 0xFFF801FFF is 2's complement of 0x7FE001(8380417) and instead of doing (A - B) we are performing (A + (-B)) and that's why the addc and adde instruction
